# Show that every nonsingular symmetric matrix is congruent to its inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Show that every nonsingular symmetric matrix is congruent to its inverse.

I know that  Two matrices A and B over a field are called congruent if there exists an invertible matrix P over the same field such that
    $$P^TAP = B$$

But how to prove the above.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$, it follows that $P^TAP=A^{-1}$ holds for $P=A^{-1}$.

Comment: This is a particular case. Is it not? I need a generalized proof.

Comment: What do you mean by "particular case"?clarify please.

Comment: Means you are taking P particularly as $A^{-1}$

Comment: Insted of proving that there exists $P$ such that $P^TAP=A^{-1}$ holds, we give the explicit expression for $P$.

Comment: @Ignat "Instead of proving that *there exists $P$ such that $P^TAP=A^{-1}$ holds*..." It is exactly what you proved.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel I just tried to say that probably there is a way to prove the existence of a solution without given the  explicit expression.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel What you want to say by "It is exactly what you proved". Is this sufficient to assume P as $A^{-1}$? Is there any other alternate method to prove the problem?

Comment: @rama_ran What you ask for is to show that "if $A$ is nonsingular symmetric matrix, then $P^TAP=A^{-1}$ for some nonsingular $P$". Obviously, $P=A^{-1}$ is a suitable *some* $P$, isn't it? What alternative to a one-line proof are you looking for?